# Prove: $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x\in G$ : $\left\langle x^{a},x^{b}\right\rangle =\left\langle x^{d}\right\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $d=\gcd(a,b)$

Prove: $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x\in G$:

$$\left\langle x^{a},x^{b}\right\rangle =\left\langle x^{d}\right\rangle. $$

My attempt was to first prove that: $$\left\langle a,b\right\rangle =\left\langle d\right\rangle $$

and then maybe rely on this proof, to show that $$\left\langle x^{a},x^{b}\right\rangle \subseteq\left\langle x^{d}\right\rangle $$

and

$$\left\langle x^{a},x^{b}\right\rangle \supseteq\left\langle x^{d}\right\rangle $$

Is this direction right? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks and sorry if I have English mistakes

Comment: d=gcd(a,b), thus there exists integers m,n, such that d=ma+nd. So $x^d=x^{ma}\cdot x^{nd}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x^a$ and $x^b$ commute, then
$$\langle x^a, x^b \rangle = \lbrace (x^a)^n(x^b)^m, n, m \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$$

so
$$\langle x^a, x^b \rangle = \lbrace x^{na+mb}, n, m \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$$

Now, $\lbrace na+mb, n,m \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace = \lbrace kd, k \in \mathbb{Z}\rbrace$ by definition of $d$ as the generator of $\langle a,b \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. So

$$\langle x^a, x^b \rangle = \lbrace x^{kd}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace = \lbrace (x^{d})^k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$$

i.e.

$$\boxed{\langle x^a, x^b \rangle = \langle x^d \rangle}$$

Comment: wow, thank you so much!

Comment: it is true only for abelian group no?

Comment: @DanielG The key point is indeed that $x^a$ and $x^b$ commute, but this is always true, even if the whole group is not abelian.

Comment: but how we assume $\left\langle x^{a},x^{b}\right\rangle $ is commutative?

Comment: Because $x^ax^b = x^{a+b} = x^{b+a} = x^b x^a$. So $x^a$ and $x^b$ always commute (even if $G$ is not abelian), and this implies directly that $\langle x^a, x^b \rangle$ is abelian.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).